# Using Div Anchor Link to hide/show divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with 4 hidden divs. If I want to link to them, I do this for example

```
<a href="#about" class="nav_text" id="about_link">About</a>
```

This shows the about div and hides the others due to my Javascript/jQuery that I wrote for it.

However, my problem arises in that the user's address bar reads as /index.php#about_content. If you were to manually type that in, it doesn't show the about_content div because it's hidden. How can I make it show that div if it's manually typed in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the current hash and show it on document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window.location.hash).show();
});
```

Comment: Looks like a great solution to me. I'll accept yours as best answer as soon as possible (Stack Overflow says I have to wait 7 minutes). Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to listen for a [`hashchange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) on the window. Once you do that, load in the element from the hash, and, if it matches, show the proper `<div>`. You'll also want to check on initial load of the page if there is something in the hash and do the same.

Not that this is IE8+ compatible only, as IE7 and below do not support the `hashchange` event. If you want to support them, you'll need to use one of the many tricks (or [plugins](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/docs/files/jquery-ba-hashchange-js.html)) for it.

PS You can find out what is in the hash using `location.hash`